To-do list that shows only 1 or a few tasks at a time?
I struggle with long intimidating to-do list. People online say try making a shorter list from that long list to focus on. And that works for me. I did it manually, for example by:

copy-pasting items from my long to-do list to another program
toggling tags and priorities in my to-do list programs
kanban-like boards, moving items to "Doing" board
writing them on paper

The problem is I inevitably got sick of it and stopped doing the moving around. I'm looking for something semi-automatic. A built-in feature of the to-do list program. Like it will refill the "Current" task list automatically after I complete those few tasks.
Basically, suppose I have 20 tasks due today. The program should select 1-5 tasks (randomly or by some other criteria) and put them under the "Current" or "Doing" list. As soon as I complete either 1 or perhaps all 5, it will automatically refill the list. I want a full-featured to-do list program that can handle repeated tasks, dates, etc. Not just shuf -n 5 from one text file to another text file.
Or something like focus-mode common in distraction-free writing softwares. The feature highlights the current line, and grays out/makes the rest invisible.
Niceties like syncing, multi-platform support, etc. are secondary. But ideally it has a linux support and not too expensive.
Perhaps one of the popular to-do list programs has hooks or plug-ins that do this?
